# Cancel the closing of in-browser Silverlight application

Tags: silverlight

I need to execute some asynchronous operations before exit Silverlight application and after that close application.
For example:

```
 RoutedEventArgs re;
 private void Application_Exit(RoutedEventArgs e){
    re=e;
    e.Cancel=true;
    ExecuteAsincOperation();
 }
 .....
 private void AsincOperationCompleted(){
     e.Cancel=false;
 }
```

How can I do it (if it possible)?

Comment: can you explain what goals you want to achieve with such code ?

Comment: In my application I use some devices in client and before reloading or closing page I must disconnect them. All disconnect operations asynchronous and take a few seconds. I have to do this in-browser for several reasons